# Rails how to access users status on project level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5, associations

I have two models User and Project which are in has_and_belongs_to_many  association 
The user model has a column status
i can access the status of a user who is in project like

```rb
project.user.status
```

but a user can be in different projects i want his status to be on project level instead of on his id

Comment: Do you mean, you want to move the status attribute to Project as a DB migration?

Comment: @SebastianPalma what i want is a status column which should be on project basis i.e.., project1.user1.status => true, project2.user2.status => false like this

Comment: Can you add your models and schema to try to replicate your scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the problem is that you need to associate the status of the user to one of potentially many projects that the user is associated with, but you are associating a single status to a single user instead of the project.

In that event, you need to abstract this association to an additional model, for instance "UserProjectStatus" which would be associated with both the User and the Project.  You can do this using the has_many, through association.  This would end up with something along the lines of:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_project_statuses
  has_many :users, through :user_project_statuses
end

class UserProjectStatus < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_project_statuses
  has_many :projects, through :user_project_statuses
end
```

There is a good overview of this any many other Rails ActiveModel associations at https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Edited for formatting. Compound assocation names in rails are also snake_case not nospace.